# How do I determine how much bandwidth a user need to use my website?

Tags: bandwidth

I am being asked to determine the bandwidth requirements for users accessing my site, but I do not even know where to start. Google hasn't helped. I do have google analytics set up if that would help?

EDIT: I'm not sure what details needed to be added. I need to figure out what the minimum bandwidth the USER needs to access my site.

I don't know if this would help answer the question, but on my site the user can upload large photos and there's no limit to what they can upload, so I'm assuming they would need more bandwidth? There are also some pretty large pages that do Solr requests and have images. Other pages are Flash intensive and some are heavy with HTML5 and javascript. The entire site is HTTPS. Again, I don't know if this would require the user to have more bandwidth (faster internet connection??)

The server is hosted on our own Linux server.

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Apache 2.2.10
SSL certficate is through GoDaddy
Uses PHP 5.2.6, MySQL 5.0.67, Drupal 6.9
```

Comment: Which control panel are you using? Check control panel you'll find it

Comment: Sorry but as the above user has stated we need more information, such as the host your using and what dashboard it uses, if one. Please edit your question and include further information so that the question can be answered without speculation.

Comment: @SimonHayter - updated question

Comment: I initially thought you wanted to know how much bandwidth your site was using by the looks of it, I think you want to know how fast a user's connection speed is? That depends on who the isp is and the location. Anyone can access your site it'll just load faster or slower depending on the speed they have. You're probably better of looking at caching etc to make your page load faster.

Comment: @Abu - this is more to gather info for a potential client. As of now, we're not working on optimization (not my call). This was a question asked by the potential client and I wasn't sure how to answer it.